# How to compare UIImageView name in an if() structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have some UIImageView's that i want to move around the screen. But the problem is that the background image is also an UIImageView, and therefor also drag able. I know that this != (not equal to) syntax below is not right, so I hope someone inhere can give tell me how to do it.

ViewController.h :

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UIImageView *circle;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *star;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *triangle;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *background;
}
```

ViewController.m :

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    UITouch *drag  = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if([touch view] != background){                              <---- LOOK HERE
        [touch view].center = [drag locationInView:self.view];
    }

}
```

Hope to find some help, and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is this code not working? != or == is fine if you want to know if you have two pointers to the same object, which I think is what you are looking for here.

Comment: Also, `touch` and `drag` are going to be the same object.

Comment: Or you can use view's assigned tag number to distinguish the view that you wanted to be moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically don't want to compare objects with normal (in)equality operators, but in this case I think your code will work fine.  When you compare objects, the pointer address is compared, so

```
if (obj1 == obj2) {
     // …
}
```

will only evaluate to TRUE if `obj1` and `obj2` are the same instance, which they are in this case.

If you want, you can use the `isEqual:` method:

```
if ([obj1 isEqual:obj2]) {
     // …
}
```

This test will include the above one, so there's no reason *not* to use this.  This method will also test class equality, and add specific comparisons for the object type.  For example, if you compare two NSString objects, the length of the string and the Unicode characters that make up the string must be identical to evaluate to TRUE.

In this particular case, though, either will work.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to identify your objects is with tags,
assign a tag to your imageViews

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
     [touch locationInView:viewBoard];

     if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
          UIImageView *tmp = (UIImageView *)touch.view;
          if (tmp.tag == imgTag) {
               // Your Code
          }
     }
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thats it, Use taging and just ommit the view with a particular tag while changing frame.center (dragging)